# Console Application - How to access the properties in JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I need to access the json properties so that I will be able to filter the result based on registers devices (either AEVL2020 or AEVL2021) but, I can't figure out how to access it. It seems like the RootObject can't access anything. I'm doing this for about 2 days now, so I need help.

Here is my json:

```
{
"registers":{
        "AEVL2020":[
            {
                "user_id": "1",
                "employee_id": "12",
                "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
                "privilege": "0"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "2",
                "employee_id": "32",
                "name": "Pedro Dela Cruz",
                "privilege": "0"
            }
        ],
        "AEVL2021":[
            {
                "user_id": "1",
                "employee_id": "29",
                "name": "Maria Del Mundo",
                "privilege": "0"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "2",
                "employee_id": "222",
                "name": "Jay Del Mundo",
                "privilege": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

my C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Admin\\source\\repos\\Practice1\\Practice1\\company1.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        // This is where the error, I can't access either AEVL2020 or AEVL2021
        foreach (var p in root.AEVL2020 || root.AEVL2021)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.user_id + p.name + p.employee_id + p.privilege);
        }
    }
}

public class AEVL2020
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string employee_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string privilege { get; set; }
}

public class AEVL2021
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string employee_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string privilege { get; set; }
}

public class Registers
{
    public List<AEVL2020> AEVL2020 { get; set; }
    public List<AEVL2021> AEVL2021 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Registers registers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "either AEVL2020 or AEVL2021"? Do you mean that you want to access whichever exists? For one, you'd need to access `root.registers.AEVL2020` or `root.registers.AEVL2021`.

Comment: Yes. If I want to type in console like AEVL2020 then it should give the result of  {
                "user_id": "1",
                "employee_id": "12",
                "name": "Juan Dela Cruz",
                "privilege": "0"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "2",
                "employee_id": "32",
                "name": "Pedro Dela Cruz",
                "privilege": "0"
            }

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Currently you have deserialized JSON, so you won't get a JSON form back without serializing it again.

Comment: I want just to output the result (when I type in console either AEVL2020 or AEVL2021 and it will show  their name and values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define single `AEVL` class for both `AEVL2020`  and `AEVL2020`  as follow:

```
public class AEVL
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string employee_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string privilege { get; set; }
}

public class Registers
{
    public List<AEVL> AEVL2020 { get; set; }
    public List<AEVL> AEVL2021 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code would be like this and you can get items based on given string:

```
var aevlProp = root.registers.GetType().GetProperty("AEVL2020");
var values = (aevlProp.GetValue(root.registers, null) as List<AEVL>);

foreach (var p in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.user_id + p.name + p.employee_id + p.privilege);
}
```

Output for  `GetProperty("AEVL2020")`;

```
1Juan Dela Cruz120
2Pedro Dela Cruz320
```

Output for  `GetProperty("AEVL2021")`;

```
1Maria Del Mundo290
2Jay Del Mundo2220
```

Comment: But, its output "1Juan Dela Cruz120
2Pedro Dela Cruz320" when I input AEVL2021 in console.

Comment: It read the two foreach when I input either AEVL2020 or AEVL2021

Comment: So do you want to output based on user input  like AEVL2020 or AEVL2021?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want.

Comment: Ok now I get it, I have updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i guess

**Given**

```
public class SomeObject
{
   public string user_id { get; set; }
   public string employee_id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string privilege { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public Dictionary<string, List<SomeObject>> registers { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "{\r\n\"registers\":{\r\n        \"AEVL2020\":[\r\n            {\r\n                \"user_id\": \"1\",\r\n                \"employee_id\": \"12\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Juan Dela Cruz\",\r\n                \"privilege\": \"0\"\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"user_id\": \"2\",\r\n                \"employee_id\": \"32\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Pedro Dela Cruz\",\r\n                \"privilege\": \"0\"\r\n            }\r\n        ],\r\n        \"AEVL2021\":[\r\n            {\r\n                \"user_id\": \"1\",\r\n                \"employee_id\": \"29\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Maria Del Mundo\",\r\n                \"privilege\": \"0\"\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"user_id\": \"2\",\r\n                \"employee_id\": \"222\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Jay Del Mundo\",\r\n                \"privilege\": \"0\"\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n}";

var r= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(input);

// choose the name you want here
var values = r.registers["<Name>"];

foreach (var p in values )
  Console.WriteLine(p.user_id + p.name + p.employee_id + p.privilege);
```